# adjusting background color gradient of a submit button with css

Tags: html, css, submit-button

Hi i want to style an input submit button which has a background as given in the attached image.The back ground image was provided, but im not sure how to implement it in the submit button so instead of using that image i tried using the css 3 color gradient properties to style the button,however, i cant get the desired color output.Any help is welcome.
[image]

CSS code so far.

```
.button {
  -moz-border-radius: 18px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #fffff 0px 0px 11px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #6E7849 0 0 10px;
  background-color: #fefefefe;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(24deg, #d8d8d8, #fefefefe);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(24deg, #d8d8d8, #fefefefe);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(24deg, #d8d8d8, #fefefefe);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(24deg, #d8d8d8, #fefefefe);
  background-image: linear-gradient(24deg, #d8d8d8, #fefefefe);
  border-radius: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  box-shadow: #fffff 0px 0px 11px;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the image. Matching the gradient fully to the image is an unnecessary pain:

```
.button {
   display:block;
   width:50px; //use actual image width
   height:50px; // use actual image height
   background:url(../img/button.png); //image file path
}

.button:hover {
 background:url(../img/button_hover.png); 
 }
```

Comment: Problem is it is not a static width button.It has rounded corners and will span according to width of text inside.

Comment: you can use the sliding doors technique:http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/

Comment: You could also just add `repeat-x` to the background declaration, if you know the height won't change. You can use `border-radius` for the rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

To use an image as the input is very simple:

```
<input type="image"src="/images/submit.gif" />
```

Comment: Not sure it's the best solution. He'll have problems with setting an hover state without messing with the SRC attr with JS

Comment: True, but I think everyone is assuming there is a hover state. The OP doesn't state that and the code seems to suggest there is none. If there is no hover state this is surely the simplest solution?

Comment: In modern browsing hover state is an implicit requirement from every button. Another advantage is that he can give the button a value which will appear on top of the BG image, which is not possible in your solution, meaning that he'll have to use the button with the text as an image, which is not very flexible and dynamic. Also, semantically speaking it is better to keep styling issues in the stylesheet, and make the HTML as semantic as possible. `type=submit` is clearly more semantic than `type=image`.

Comment: In modern browsing hover state is an implicit requirement from every button. --- Not sure what you mean by this, could you elaborate? Although you are correct about adding text for screen readers/ search engines. And of course this class could Be used for all buttons rather than creating a new image each time so Ill agree the background image is better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the way to make this button using sliding door technique.However still in jeopardy to style it in disabled state.
This link helped me alot http://www.springload.co.nz/love-the-web/dynamic-submit-buttons

css

```
div.submit_button { 
   background: transparent url('common/images/bg-submit2.png') no-repeat 0 0; 
   display: block; 
   float: left; 
   height: 27px; /* total height of the button */ 
   padding-left: 15px; /* end width */ 
} 

span.submit_button_end { 
   background: #fff url('common/images/bg-submit2.png') no-repeat 100% 0; /*  used a sprite image */ 
   display: block; 
   float: left; 
   font-weight: normal; 
   height: 27px; /* total height of the button */ 
} 

input.submit_input { 
   font-size: 13px; 
   font-weight:bold;
   background: none; 
   border: none; 
   padding: 0 0 2px 15px; /* end width */ 
   color: #1b1d60; 
   cursor: pointer; 
   position: relative; 
   height: 25px; 
   line-height: 25px; 
   left: -15px;  
   margin-right: -15px; 
   padding-right: 15px; 
} 

input.submit_input:hover {color: #fff;} 

div.submit_button:hover {background-position: 0 100%;} 

div.submit_button:hover span.submit_button_end {background-position: 100% 100%;}
```

HTML

```
 <div class='submit_button'> 
   <span class='submit_button_end'> 
     <input class='submit_input' type='submit'  value='Submit button' tabindex='#' /> 
   </span> 
</div>
```